# Do windows API work with windows form

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, taskmanager

I am trying to create a mini task manager where I can show all the process and details. I am able to get all the details by using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, OpenProcess etc. Now for GUI I am not sure what to use? I can use windows form or windows APIs. Windows forms can make my job easier but I read somewhere that windows form won't work with win apis We can't mix managed and unmanaged code(I am not sure. I don't understand much of this). Can anybody guide me what to do in this? Can I use the forms or I can only use APIs. Is there any better way of doing this, kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that you can't use Windows APIs with Windows Forms? They need to be correct because that's wrong. There is no reason you can't P/Invoke unmanaged code from managed applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both together.

Simply choose what you you are familiar with. The goal is to make it done and working, isn't it? :-)